# Moving from pair/tuple elements via structured binding

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

Given `std::pair<std::set<int>, std::set<int>> p`, what is the right syntax to move its elements via structured binding?

How to do

```
std::set<int> first_set  = std::move(p.first);
std::set<int> second_set = std::move(p.second);
```

via structured binding syntax? Is the following equivalent to the above?

```
auto&& [first_set, second_set] = p;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the following equivalent to the above?

No, there is no move operation, only the member variable of `p` is bound to the lvalue reference `first_set` and `second_set`. You should do this:

```
auto [first_set, second_set] = std::move(p);
```